# Rstudio outputs an error into the console while editing script

Tags: r, rstudio

I am working on a project on Rstudio and something wired has become to happen: each time I write something into a script Rstudio automatically writes the following error into the console:

```
Error in rep.int(vectorNames[i], length(vector[[i]])) : 
  unimplemented type 'NULL' in 'rep3'
```

and a label appears under the cursor: "R code execution error".
Appart form this *visual* bug, everything is working properly. Does anyone have the same issue ?

Comment: Any chance you can provide more information? If possible, a reproducible example (with code + actions to make RStudio emit these errors) would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've just experienced this issue. In my case, I guess it must be related to the NAMESPACE file from the package.

I can see a discussion about this subject here on [R Studio support site](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207912898-Auto-complete-fails-in-function).

Citation from the source mentioned above:

> There are two times when we run the code that could be emitting this error:
>
> - When attempting to retrieve completions from the package's NAMESPACE file,
> - When attempting to retrieve completions for native routines (e.g. for within a '.Call()' call).
>
> Can you recall if you had been editing the package's NAMESPACE file before seeing this error? Alternatively, have you been using 'devtools::load_all()' or other similar machinery?

And to clearly answer your question:
**Yes! I am having the same issue!** (Damn it! :) )

**LATER EDIT:**

I've got rid of the problem by closing the project and reopening it again.